# Update command in SQLite3 gives strange results

Tags: sqlite

```
My SQLite3 table consists the following data:

ID          site_name   site_type_code  site_type   cache_type  php         letsencrypt  mysql     
----------  ----------  --------------  ----------  ----------  ----------  -----------  ----------
17          four.com    php             PHP         disabled    5.6         disabled     no
```

When I try to update few columns using:

```
UPDATE ee_site_data
SET
    site_type_code="php",
    site_type="PHP",
    php="7.0",
    cache_type="disabled",
    mysql="no",
    letsencrypt="disabled"
WHERE site_name="four.com"
```

I get this as output:

```
ID          site_name   site_type_code  site_type   cache_type  php         letsencrypt  mysql     
----------  ----------  --------------  ----------  ----------  ----------  -----------  ----------
17          four.com    5.6             5.6         disabled    7.0         disabled     no
```

The columns `site_type_code` and `site_type` both have values as `5.6`

I don't know why this is happening!
My table schema is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `ee_site_data` (
    `ID`    INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    `site_name` TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    `site_type_code`    TEXT NOT NULL,
    `site_type` TEXT NOT NULL,
    `cache_type`    TEXT,
    `php`   TEXT,
    `letsencrypt`   TEXT,
    `mysql` TEXT
);
```

Comment: Are you _certain_ that the above `UPDATE` is what you actually ran?  I don't see how this could happen except by running another update which assigns `5.6` to those two columns.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes I ran exactly that. I copy pasted them from terminal itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQLite the way to escape a column name is to use double quotes.  Hence, when you made the following two assignments you actually were referring to the `php` *column*:

```
site_type_code = "php"
site_type = "PHP"
```

But double quotes also appear to be overloaded as meaning a string literal.  Hence, in the following assignments you were assigning to string literals:

```
php = "7.0"
cache_type = "disabled"
mysql = "no"
letsencrypt = "disabled"
```

Because no columns by these names exist, the right hand assignments default to string literals.

To avoid this ambiguity altogether, you should have run the following query:

```
UPDATE ee_site_data
SET
    site_type_code = 'php',
    site_type = 'PHP',
    php = '7.0',
    cache_type = 'disabled',
    mysql = 'no',
    letsencrypt = 'disabled'
WHERE site_name = 'four.com'
```

This query uses proper string literals in single quotes, and there is no chance of accidentally referring to a column.

Comment: The explanation helped a lot! Thank you!